# Listen to a serial port within Java from a glass fish server running a web app

Tags: java, web-applications, glassfish, serial-port, push

Hope you guys can help me out.

1. I have information coming into a serial connection on my laptop.
2. This information is passed to the business logic in a web application - running on Glassfish V3.1.1 [business rules and database reading/persistence happens here]
3. Depending on what is returned by the business logic, a webpage is updated (using a4j:push)

My questions are:

- Is it possible to use the Java comm and RxTx libraries from a glassfish server to get the serial data?
- I want to "listen" to the serial port, so that when something comes through (wait for the terminating character), then information is passed to business logic. I don't want to poll the serial port (needs to be real time)

I really would appreciate any answers, 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java EE way of doing this is to implement your serial communication code as JCA Inbound Resource Adapter, than would trigger an message-driven bean, which would in turn trigger your business logic (EJB invocation, I suppose) and then trigger push event -- probably over JMS.

Less conformant way would be to fire communication thread directly in your webapp, e. g. in servlet or application-scoped bean. This solution it will make Java EE architects weep, but will be much more simple and should work equally well in simple conditions, if you don't expect concurrency issues (that would be the case if you'd write to serial port) or require transactions (e. g. message needs not to be replayed in case of optimistic lock error in business layer).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i have since realised that my original architecture was wrong, as if the web application went offline that it would bring the whole system down.

I have since changed the architecture to two separate applications:

1) Standalone JavaEE app listening to serial connection and dealing with business logic depending on information.
2) Web app for admin type tasks.

Thank you for your answer anyway.